# How to construct the chiral electroweak Lagrangian?

Tags: differential-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation

The electroweak Lagrangian before symmetry breaking is [defined here as](https://universe-review.ca/R15-12-QFT16.htm):

$$L_{ew}=L_g+L_f+L_{hy}$$

where

$$L_{higgs.yukawa} = (\bar {D_\mu \phi})(D^\mu \phi) - m^2\bar \phi \phi - \alpha (\bar \phi \phi)^2 - \beta(\bar L \phi R + \bar R \bar \phi L)$$

where the Higgs field is defined as a 2-component complex number vector field,

$$\phi = \begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ and

$$D_\mu\phi = \frac{d}{dx^\mu}\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{ig^{'}}{2}B_\mu\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{ig}{2}W^0_\mu\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{ig}{2}W^1_\mu\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{ig}{2}W^2_\mu\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$D^μ\phi=\sum_{\nu}^4 η^{μν}(D_ν\phi)$$

1. What vector form must $\vec L$ and $\vec R$ take in order for the product $\color{red}{\bar L \phi R}$ and $\color{red}{\bar R \bar \phi L}$ to be legal matrix multiplication?

$$\begin{bmatrix} . & . \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} . \\ . \end{bmatrix} = ?$$

---

For the [non-chiral analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction) with scalar $\phi$, let

$$L=L_\phi+L_\Psi+L_{\phi,\Psi}$$

Define the parts as

$$L_\phi=\frac{1}{2}(D_\mu\phi)(D^\mu\phi) - V(\phi)$$

$$L_\Psi = i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\frac{d\Psi}{d\mu} - m_1\bar\Psi\Psi$$

$$L_{\phi,\Psi}=-g\bar\Psi\phi\Psi$$

Then,

$$L = \frac{1}{2}(D_\mu\phi)(D^\mu\phi) - V(\phi) + i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\frac{d\Psi}{d\mu} - m_1\bar\Psi\Psi -g\bar\Psi\phi\Psi$$

Let $V(\phi)$ be chosen as

$$V(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}m_2^2\phi^2 + m_3\phi^4$$

Then,

$$L = \frac{1}{2}(D_\mu\phi)(D^\mu\phi) - \frac{1}{2}m_2^2\phi^2 -m_3\phi^4 + i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\frac{d\Psi}{d\mu} - m_1\bar\Psi\Psi -g\bar\Psi\phi\Psi$$

Let also $\phi$ become a complex scalar

$$\phi = \phi_1 + i\phi_2$$

or a quarternion scalar
$$\phi = \phi_1 + i\phi_2 + j\phi_3 + k\phi_4$$

Finally, shift $\phi$ by some pre-determined distance $\Delta \phi$ in the complex or quarternion space.

$$\phi \rightarrow \phi + \Delta \phi$$

2. Is the model construction is already $\color{green}{complete}$ at this step, ie. the Euler-Lagrange and equation of motion will now exhibit all behaviors which can be analyzed as symmetry breaking, mass gaining, etc?

Comment: 1. $D^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}D_\nu$. 2. A count of multiplet indices not allowed on the Lagrangian implies $\beta$ needs at least one.

Comment: @J.G. thank you very much, that solves $D^\mu$. Could you help shed some light as to how the "left-handed lepton" $L$ and "right-handed lepton" $R$ might look like component-wise?

Comment: My guess is $\beta_a(\bar{L}_b\phi_aR_b+\bar{R}_b\bar{\phi}_aL_b)$. By the way, you can also have $\mu=0$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you. I think i shall work through some Yukawa L examples before coming back to the chirality's mathematical form.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model) example,

[image]

Piecing together the operation,

1. $\bar \nu_e, \nu_e, \bar e, e$ are each $4x1$ Dirac vector fields.
2. $W_+^\mu$ is a $1x1$ gauge field component.
3. $\gamma_\mu$ is a $4x4$ Dirac matrix.
4. $\tau^+$ is a $2x2$ Pauli matrix.
5. $g$ is a $1x1$ coupling constant.

$$LHS = -\frac{g}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\bar \nu_e & \bar e \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} \gamma_\mu W_+^\mu\begin{bmatrix} \nu_e \\ e \end{bmatrix}$$

$\gamma_\mu$ and $W_+^\mu$ acts on each *individual* component $\nu_e$ and $e$,

$$= -\frac{g}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\bar \nu_e & \bar e \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_\mu W_+^\mu \nu_e \\ \gamma_\mu W_+^\mu e \end{bmatrix}$$

$\tau^+$ acts to the right via matrix multiplication,

$$= -\frac{g}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\bar \nu_e & \bar e \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_\mu W_+^\mu e \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$\begin{bmatrix}\bar \nu_e & \bar e \end{bmatrix}$ acts to the right via matrix multiplication,

$$= -\frac{g}{2}\bar \nu_e\gamma_\mu W_+^\mu e$$

which equals the RHS.